# delete cookies which have not been accessed in the last x days

Tags: firefox, cookies

Using Firefox. I would like to get rid of "obsolete" cookies. By "obsolete" I mean cookies which have not been accessed by any website in the last x days.

I have searched high and low but I have not found how to do that. What I have found is, among others:

- restrict the lifetime of all cookies (about:config -> network.cookie.lifetimePolicy).
- whitelist or blacklist domains (firefox preferences -> privacy -> cookie exceptions).
- delete all cookies from the last x hours (firefox history -> clear recent history).

None of that is what I want.

I want to delete all cookies which have not been accessed by any website in the last x days.

Comment: Most likely, an extension is needed for this.

Comment: Not sure if this accomplishes what you want, but I have Firefox to *not* automatically accept cookies, and instead am prompted when cookies try to install.  In the prompt dialog box, I choose to store the cookie as a "session" cookie rather than a "standard" cookie.

Comment: I used this request to show the latest cookies `select datetime(lastAccessSec , 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as "lastAccessTime", * from (SELECT  lastAccessed/1000000 as "lastAccessSec", * FROM moz_cookies order by lastAccessed desc LIMIT 50)`. It runs from SQLite firefox manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**Cookie Time**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookie-time/) extension can be configured to automatically delete cookies that haven't been used for a specified time (expired). It also has a separate setting to force expire / delete *all* cookies that are beyond a specified age.

[image: Cookie Time configuration screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I did some research.

1. Cookies are stored in the [`cookies.sqlite`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Cookies) file in the firefox profile directory.
2. The file is a sqlite database.
3. The timestamp of the last access is stored in the [`lastAccessed`](http://renaissancesecurity.blogspot.com/2011/04/firefox-4-browser-forensics-part-4.html) column in the `moz_cookies` table.
4. The format of `lastAccessed` is some [`PRTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/PRTime) format, which is basically the unix epoch time with microseconds.

The following query will list every cookie which has not been accessed in the last 14 days.

```
select host, name from moz_cookies
where lastaccessed < strftime('%s000000', 'now', '-14 days')
order by lastaccessed;
```

I just learned some SQL for this, so it might very well be that this query can be done better.

The following query will delete all those cookies.

```
delete from moz_cookies
where lastaccessed < strftime('%s000000', 'now', '-14 days');
```

Here is a quick and dirty shell script which does the job. You will need the `sqlite3` command installed on your system.

```
#!/bin/sh

DAYS="14"

SELECT="select host, name"
DELETE="delete"
FROM="from moz_cookies"
OBSOLETE="strftime('%s000000', 'now', '-$DAYS days')"
WHERE="where lastaccessed < $OBSOLETE"
ORDER="order by lastaccessed"

SELECTQUERY="$SELECT $FROM $WHERE $ORDER;"
DELETEQUERY="$DELETE $FROM $WHERE;"

printf '%s\n' "$SELECTQUERY" | sqlite3 cookies.sqlite
```

Comment: What is the '%s000000' format? I see that `SELECT datetime(strftime('%s000000','now'), 'unixepoch', 'localtime')` prints extreemly wiered negative time, `-1413-03-01 15:07:12`, whereas '%s' is fine, it produces `2014-07-22 16:01:17`, which is really now. At the same time, I see that firefox uses the wierd time format. What is that?

Comment: Ok, 000000 just means that firefox stores millions of seconds instead of seconds. So, if I want to translate the firefox time into standard epoch date (%s stands for the num of seconds since 1970), I can just divide the firefox date by 1000000. This helped me to realize this, http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/972178#answer-482511